PKS12 pfx certificate doens't load in python playwright
I'm using playwright python and the usage of PKS12 certificates seems not be working properly.
We try to follow the playwright documentation and this example from stackoverflow too, but none of these seems to be working properly, the certificate doesn't show up in the list of options for login.
import asyncio
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def page_launch_playwright():

    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    device = playwright.devices["Desktop Firefox"]
    device['user_agent'] = UserAgent().firefox
    device['viewport'] = {'width': 1366, 'height': 768}
    # https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672#issuecomment-1243648223
    # convert old certificate to new pfx
    # openssl pkcs12 -in oldPfxFile.pfx -nodes -legacy -out decryptedPfxFile.tmp
    # openssl pkcs12 -in decryptedPfxFile.tmp -export -out newPfxFile.pfx
    # base example https://playwright.dev/python/docs/release-notes#version-146
    device["client_certificates"] = [
        {
            "origin": 'https://website.com',
            "pfxPath": './newPfxFile.pfx',
            "passphrase": 'mypass',
        }
    ]


    url_base_path = "https://website.com"

    launch_config = {}
    launch_config["headless"] = False
    launch_config["timeout"] = 10000.0
    launch_config["proxy"] = None
    launch_config["slow_mo"] = 190

    browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(**launch_config)

    context = await browser.new_context(**device)

    await context.add_init_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

    page_driver = await context.new_page()

    await page_driver.goto(url_base_path)

    await page_driver.wait_for_timeout(2000.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(page_launch_playwright())

What we have been done wrong on this example?

This feature is only released around 2 months ago. Is your installed playwright package version 1.46.0 or 1.47.0? Does it work if you use other options like pfx or certPath + keyPath ?

Yes, last version and doesn't show the certificate once you run the script. It is not working with it.

To get more clarity what's going on as I have no idea of what files your using or website, can you try this:
import asyncio
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import os


async def page_launch_playwright():

    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    device = playwright.devices["Desktop Firefox"]
    device['user_agent'] = UserAgent().firefox
    device['viewport'] = {'width': 1366, 'height': 768}

    pfx_file_path = os.path.abspath('./newPfxFile.pfx')

    # Ensure the certificate is correctly attached
    device["client_certificates"] = [
        {
            "origin": 'https://website.com',
            "pfx": pfx_file_path,  # Ensure you are passing the correct absolute path
            "passphrase": 'mypass',  # Correct passphrase for the certificate
        }
    ]

    url_base_path = "https://website.com"

    launch_config = {
        "headless": False,
        "timeout": 10000,
        "proxy": None,
        "slow_mo": 190
    }

    browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(**launch_config)

    context = await browser.new_context(**device)

    print("Loaded client certificates: ", context.client_certificates())

    await context.add_init_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

    page_driver = await context.new_page()

    await page_driver.goto(url_base_path)

    await page_driver.wait_for_timeout(5000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(page_launch_playwright())


There is not much details in the question itself, but i will try to help you.
From the code you provided it seems like you're following the documentation correctly, but there is thing you should double check.

Check if the website actually requires a client certificate for authentication. If not, the certificate won't show up in the list of options.
Check that newPfxFile.pfx file is in the correct location (./newPfxFile.pfx) and is a valid PKCS12 certificate.
Check that the passphrase is correct.
Ensure that the origin URL matches the website you're trying to access.

If you check all this and still have a problem.

Enable verbose logging to see if there are any errors related.
Using a tool like openssl to verify the certificate file and its contents.

Again, there is not much detail, and i'm not a python professional in this matter.
